# Move sidecap images to the end of the document

Tags: floats, positioning, sidecap, endfloat

I'm trying to move all the figures to the end of my document, so I can judge its length based on text alone (My undergraduate thesis has to be no more then 20 pages, not counting figures).

I've been doing this by loading

```
\usepackage[nofiglist,notablist]{endfloat}
```

But this only moves normal figures, not SCfigures from sidecap, which I make extensive use of. Is there a way I could get them to all move to the end of the document easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation of `endfloat`, you can try

```
\usepackage[nofiglist,notablist]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{SCfigure}{figure}
```

which might work (the authors don't guarantee it for all "figure-like" environments). The syntax is

```
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{<environment>}{<base environment>}
```

that tells that `<environment>` should be treated like `<base environment>` (`table` or `figure`) for the purposes of `endfloat`, but will eventually be typeset according to the rules of `<environment>`.

Comment: Man, I missed that even though I read the manual. Admittedly, I wasn't looking for it at the time, but still. Sorry to have bothered you.